# Add delay to jquery mouseleave tooltip hover

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I’m trying to edit a WordPress plugin’s built-in tooltip functionality. Currently it disappears immediately on `mouseleave`. I just need it to stay put for a second or two.

I’ve read through plenty of similar questions but I can’t figure out where to add a timeout delay to the plugin’s existing code:

```
init_tooltip();
$(window).resize(init_tooltip);
target.data('is_moving', false);

var remove_tooltip = function () {
  if (target.data('is_moving')) {
    return;
  }

  tooltip.removeClass(fadin).addClass(fadeout);
  var speed = 15000;

  tooltip.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, speed, function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  if (!tiphtml && !is_swatch && !is_swatch_desc && !is_swatch_lbl_desc && !is_swatch_img && !is_swatch_img_lbl && !is_swatch_img_desc && !is_swatch_img_lbl_desc) {
    target.attr('title', tip);
  }
};

target
  .on('tmmovetooltip', function () {
    target.data('is_moving', true);
    init_tooltip(1);
  })
  .on('mouseleave tmhidetooltip', remove_tooltip);

target.closest('label').on('mouseleave tmhidetooltip', remove_tooltip);

tooltip.on('click', remove_tooltip);

targets.closest('label').on('mouseenter tmshowtooltip', showtooltip);
targets.on('mouseenter tmshowtooltip', showtooltip);

return targets;
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the plugin is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've updated this answer with a best-guess to only get the tooltip delay to happen on mouse out. The gist of it is that you need two functions

You need to wrap the insides of the `remove_tooltip` function in a `setTimeout()` with your desired delay. Change the number at the end to change the amount of delay.

Replace your code with the following:

```
    init_tooltip();
    $(window).resize(init_tooltip);
    target.data('is_moving', false);

    var remove_tooltip = function () {
      removeTooltipCore();
    };

    var remove_tooltip_with_delay = function () {
      setTimeout( function () {
        removeTooltipCore();
    }, 1000); //1 second delay
};

function removeTooltipCore() {
    if (target.data('is_moving')) {
            return;
          }

          tooltip.removeClass(fadin).addClass(fadeout);
          var speed = 15000;

          tooltip.animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, speed, function () {
            $(this).remove();
          });

          if (!tiphtml && !is_swatch && !is_swatch_desc && !is_swatch_lbl_desc && !is_swatch_img && !is_swatch_img_lbl && !is_swatch_img_desc && !is_swatch_img_lbl_desc) {
            target.attr('title', tip);
          }
}

target
  .on('tmmovetooltip', function () {
    target.data('is_moving', true);
    init_tooltip(1);
  })
  .on('tmhidetooltip', remove_tooltip)
  .on('mouseleave', remove_tooltip_with_delay);

target.closest('label').on('tmhidetooltip', remove_tooltip);
target.closest('label').on('mouseleave', remove_tooltip_with_delay);

tooltip.on('click', remove_tooltip);
```

Comment: You are a saint. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. For reference, this plugin is called 'Extra Product Options' for Woocommerce

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd appreciate it if you can accept this answer as correct, it gives me a lot of rep :)

Comment: Oops. Forgot to. New guy here. It actually only sorta worked. The delay would kick in regardless of mouseleave. If you have any other ideas that'd be great but if not, no biggie!

Comment: @Brian7865 it looks like you're assigning the same function for both `mouseleave` and `tmhidetooltip` - if you only want the delay on `mouseleave`, you should have two instances of the function, one with delay and one without. I've updated my answer to demonstrate this approach. Please forgive me if this isn't 100% free of syntax errors or doesn't work perfectly - I've never worked with this specific plugin before, I'm just making a best-guess based on my general knowledge. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give it a try when I can. Either way I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Brian7865 I updated my answer with a shot at how this would work.